# Como aplicar un loader en una determinada posicion sin bloquear

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Necesito un loader para informarle al usuario de que se esta obteniendo información que solicito. Normalmente utilizo **LoadingOverla**y, pero en este caso no lo puedo utilizar ya que necesito que al usuario no se le "bloquee" la pantalla como hace este script y ademas poder posicionarlo abajo a la derecha de la pantalla, otra cosa que no permite este loader.
Cuál podría utilizar, porque probe **spin.j**s pero tampoco me dio resultados.

Comment: Hola @iMSn20, muestra esa parte de tu código o has un code snippet para poder ver que es lo que quieres hacer

Comment: Es que no podría mostrar nada, porque no es tema del codigo. Es que el loader LoadingOverlay no te deja posicionar y ademas se pone en toda la pantalla, sin permitir hacer clic en otro lado o seguir utilizando la aplicación. Quería ver si alguien tiene un loader que permita esto

Comment: entonces solo debes programarlo tú. Lo que yo hago es seleccionar un div donde se va a mostar el loader y ponerlo ahi. Para el loader puedes usar bootstrap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que hago es usar la librería [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) y [JQuery](https://jquery.com/) para ocultar el elemento div que contiene el loader y usando los selectores de JQuery mostrar el loader cuando sea oportuno

```js
$(function(){
  $("#buscar").click(function(){
    $(".spinner-border").removeClass("invisible");
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<button id="buscar">Buscar</button>
<div class="spinner-border text-primary invisible" role="status">
  <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
</div>
```